# Max difference between update timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table:

```
id | updated_at
1  | 2018-10-22T21:00:00Z
2  | 2018-10-22T21:02:00Z
```

I'd like to find the largest delta for a given day between closest updated timestamps.  For example, if there were 5 rows:

```
id | updated_at
1  | 2018-10-22T21:00:00Z
2  | 2018-10-22T21:02:00Z
3  | 2018-10-22T21:05:00Z
4  | 2018-10-22T21:06:00Z
5  | 2018-10-22T21:16:00Z
```

The largest delta is between 4 and 5 (10 minutes).  Note that really when comparing, I just want to find the next closest updated_at timestamp and then give me the `max` of this.  I feel like I'm messing up the subquery to do this.

```
 with nearest_time(time_diff)
 as
 (
   select datediff('minute', updated_at as u1, (select updated_at from table where updated_at > u1 limit 1) as u2)
   group by updated_at::date
 )

 select max(select time_diff from nearest_time);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag` to get the updated_at from the previous row and then get the max difference per day.

```
select dt_updated_at,max(time_diff)
from (select updated_at::date as dt_updated_at
      ,updated_at - lag(updated_at) over(partition by updated_at::date order by updated_at) as time_diff
      from tbl
     ) t 
group by dt_updated_at
```

One more option using `DISTINCT ON` (*only works on Postgres*..as the question was initially tagged Postgres, keeping this answer)

```
select distinct on
 (updated_at::date) 
 updated_at::date as dt_updated_at 
,updated_at-lag(updated_at) over(partition by updated_at::date order by updated_at) as diff
from dates
order by updated_at::date,diff desc
nulls last
```

Answer (score 2):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8251caf99b3b865171786a92b3c86daa)

```
SELECT 
    lead(updated) OVER (ORDER BY updated) - updated as diff 
FROM dates 
ORDER BY diff DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1;
```

Using [window function `LEAD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) allows you to get the value of the next row: In this case you can get the next timestamp.

With that you can do a substraction, sorting the results descending and take the first value.